# WinRt App keyUp and keyDown events does not working after navigated from my page

Tags: c#, .net, winrt-xaml

My code for handling the KeyDown and the KeyUp events on the page:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += GameArea_KeyDown;
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += GameArea_KeyUp;

        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

                Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown -= GameArea_KeyDown;
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp -= GameArea_KeyUp;


        }
        ....
```

I have  2 pages in my application. This is  Page1 and Page2. On the Page1 I have one  button for navigation to the Page2. On Page2 I have 2 elements. They are: button2 for proceeding to the Page 1 and GameArea element.  I'm using MVVM and comands to navigation on the pages.

My work steps: On the Page1 I clicked the button1 and navigated to the Page2. On the Page2 I worked with KeyUp and KeyDown events in the  GameArea element. After some work, I clicked button2 and went back to the Page1. On the Page1 I again clicked button1 and went to the Page2, but KeyUp and KeyDown events did not work. I waited a few seconds (30-50) and typed some keys on the keyboard. After that , key up/down events worked well.

What is happening with keyUp and keyDown events?

I'm apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Could you clarify your description of the problem? For me it is a bit unclear what is happening, maybe you should list the steps needed to reproduce the problem in an ordered list. However, the code seems to be correct to me, are you sure your methods are not being called? How did you test it? Did you try to set breakpoints in your GameArea_KeyDown and GameArea_KeyUp methods?

Comment: Yes I did. I put breakpoints in GameArea_KeyDown/KeyUp methods, but after navigation I was not input to these handlers.

Comment: I have a 2 pages on my application. This is a Page1 and a Page2.
On the Page1 I have a button1 for navigation to the Page2, and on the Page2
I have a button2 for navigation to the Page1.

Comment: My work steps:
On the Page1 I clicked the button1 and navigated to the Page2. 
On the Page2 I worked with KeyUp and KeyDown events on an element GameArea.
After some work I click the button2 and go back to the Page1.
On the Page1 I again click button1 and go to the Page2, but KeyUp and KeyDown events did not working.

Comment: Maybe, I think, it is due to focus.
Because after I was clicking a button2 (button2 is on top of the GameArea element ), this button had a focus. And after I navigated to Page1 and go back to the Page1,and focus of the GameArea element is lost.

Comment: I think it's not supposed to do anything with focus, because you are subscribing to the KeyUp event of the CoreWindow, so you should get an event regardless of where the focus is. Could you try to debug the OnNavgatedTo and From methods with breakpoints to make sure that they get called every time you navigate to and from your page?

Comment: Mark thank you for your help! After debuging I found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because after navigation with using MVVM and commands - the UI thread is blocked.
And, if I use dispatcher for navigation, than the problems is solved.

```
 public void NavigateTo<TPage>(object parameter)
    {
        if (_rootFrame != null)
        {
            CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;

            dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                () => _rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(TPage), parameter));
        }
    }
```